Calling non async func inside Task in Swift
I have written the following sample code for loading an image from a photo picker then cropping and displaying the cropped photo in UI.
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct AsyncDemoView: View {
    @State private var selectedPhotoItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @State private var loadingImage = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            if loadingImage {
                ProgressView()
                    .tint(.primary)
            }
            if let selectedImage {
                Image(uiImage: selectedImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
            PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedPhotoItem, matching: .images) {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Image(systemName: "photo.fill")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    
                }
                .tint(.primary)
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedPhotoItem, { _, _ in
                loadImage()
            })
        }
        
    }
    
    private func loadImage() {
        loadingImage = true
        Task {
            do {
                guard let imageData = try await selectedPhotoItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self),
                      let image = UIImage(data: imageData),
                      let cropImage = cropImage(image: image) else {
                    loadingImage = false
                    return
                }
                
                await MainActor.run {
                    selectedImage = cropImage
                    loadingImage = false
                }
            }
            catch {
                loadingImage = false
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func cropImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        let minLength = min(image.size.width, image.size.height)
        let x = image.size.width / 2 - minLength / 2
        let y = image.size.height / 2 - minLength / 2
        let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: minLength, height: minLength)
        
        if let cImage = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: rect) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: cImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
        }
        return nil
    }
}

I understand that the loadTransferable method is async throwing so I need to call it inside a Task. But the code following it is not async. I would like it to be so as not to block the UI.
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
let cropImage = cropImage(image: image)

So is it correct to use them inside of the Task? Also, I update the image via MainActor.run to update the UI on the main thread and also toggle boolean loadingImage to show progress view as I read. We must do UI updates on the main thread, so am I doing it correctly? But what about setting loadingImage in guard else condition and catch block? Do I need to use MainActor.run here too? Sorry for any mistake, English is not my first language.

Unrelated but if you skip the guard and use if instead you can refactor your code to set loadingImage = false only once at the end of the task code, possibly also selectedImage and then you have only one re-entrance to the main actor

And you should run your code inside a .task modifier, maybe you could even use .task(id: selectedPhotoItem) here.

.task to call your backgound async func defined outside of View struct and return a result that you use to set on state

To fix the problem of blocking the UI you need to declare the func outside of the View because that usually ends up being main actor for a number of reasons. You also need to return the loaded image, e.g.

// background thread because this struct is not main actor
struct ImageLoader {
    private func loadImage(_ item: PhotosPickerItem) async throws -> UIImage {
        // loading and cropping code
        return croppedImage
    }
}

// this is main actor because View is 
struct AsyncDemoView: View {
    @State private var selectedPhotoItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @State private var loadingImage = false
    @State private var message = ""

//    @Environment(\.imageLoader) var imageLoader // better way


    var body: some View {
        // Views
            .task(id: selectedPhotoItem) {
                if let selectedPhotoItem {
                    loadingImage = true
                    message = ""
                    try {
                        selectedImage = ImageLoader().loadImage(selectedPhotoItem) // better is imageLoader.loadImage(...
                    }
                    catch {
                        message = "Error loading"
                    }
                    loadingImage = false
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

To improve this further you could also put this in a struct ImageLoader in an EnvironmentKey so you can mock it for previews.
